# How to calculate multiple occurances cumulatively in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, sum

I have been playing around with this for a while without decent simple solution. Tried sum(if , match, and many others.

So what I would like to accomplish is to have sheet that has Seller, Product and Volume like below, and then from that count how many products of type A one seller sold and so on. e.g.

With an function it would pull out from A column unique names to E4:E6
Then within an function it would pull out unique products from B column to F3:H3
Then within an function it would calculate the table there between e.g so that Joe has sold total 4 apples and 5 bananas but no oranges

Example Excel Sheet
[image]

I first thought this would not be an complex, but I can't pull it off.

This is my first question here ever, so hope it went even remotely right.

Comment: Pivot table? http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Answer (score 1):

1. On the sample Excel sheet you have shown, go to column Z (I just want to bury the secret here)
2. In cell Z4, type the formula "=A4 & "-" & B4"
3. In the cell F4, type the formula "=SUMIF($Z$4:$Z$10,"=" & $E4 & "-" & F$3,$C$4:$C$10)"
4. Copy and paste it to all cells in the range F4 to H6

(All cell reference mentioned above are in accordance to the sample excel sheet you have published. hence use the same sheet)

Comment: Yes, this did it, tnx. Voted + but doesn't show up as I'm still newbie here.  There is one addition, on 2. the formula z4 needs to be copied down until 10. Could you share bit more light on the formulas as they are really efficient but hard to understand at first sight.

Comment: @PaulaPolvi , you may click on the small "tick" beside this answer post to "accept" this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following example I prepared:

[image]

**The formula:**

```
=SUMIFS([sum_range],[criteria_range1],[criteria1],[criteria_range2],[criteria2])
```

**Explanation:**

[sum_range]: summaraize values in specific range (in above example: C2:C5)

[criteria_range1]: Search in specific range for [critieria1] value. (in above example search for example for Joe in A2:A5 range)

[criteria_range2]: Search in specific range for [critieria2] value. (in above example search for example for Apple in B2:A5 range)

**The above example:**

Joe + Apple [F2]:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5,$E2,$B$2:$B$5,F$1)
```

Eric + Apple [F3]:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5,$E3,$B$2:$B$5,F$1)
```

Joe + Banana [G2]:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5,$E2,$B$2:$B$5,G$1)
```

Eric + Banana [G3]:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5,$E3,$B$2:$B$5,G$1)
```

Pay attention, the formula is the same, only the row and columns indices varied. Excep the cells where there is a '$'.
The $ sign causes the cell column or row or both in a formula to be fixed.